# I just created two dropdown menus one after the other and the contents of the first one do not allow me to close the second one

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the code : css

```
.dropdown {position: relative;}
.dropdown-menu {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 101%; background-color: white; padding: .75rem; border-radius: .25rem; box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1); opacity: 0; transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out; }
.dropdown.active > .link + .dropdown-menu {opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Right-click on the  one you cannot close and choose inspect. See that one is overlapping the other. Fix the overlapping